# Rails 3.2 _partial.scss.erb variable scoping: full compilation before @import?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sass, asset-pipeline, erb

Smarter minds than mine:

We have several SCSS partials which define mixins, variables, and other useful goodies. We now have need of using some embedded ruby in one of these partials, like so:

**_partial.scss.erb**

```
 $text-color: #555555;
 <%= "" %>
```

**app.scss**

```
@import "partial"
.text {color: $text-color;}
```

If the file is named `_partial.scss` it works fine (without any ruby, of course). When named `.erb` I get an error that the variable `$text-color` is not defined.

I'm using the `sass_rails_patch` gem. I can't say for sure, but I believe the _partial.scss.erb is being compiled all the way into _partial.css and *then* being imported into app.scss. This may be why `$text-color` is getting stripped out.

Any advice on how to get this flow working the way I expect? I would expect:

1. Evaluate ruby in `.erb` files, generate valid `.scss`.
2. Run `@import` statements on `.scss`
3. Do all the other SCSS compilation stuff, generate `.css`.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe this will help you: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives this is where you can specify the order of compilation.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely want to use Ruby script in your SCSS files in order to build asset paths (and that MUST be the only reason). If this is the reason, you can use SCSS functions to build them up :

Instead of:

```
background-image: url(<%= asset_path('general/side_shadow.png') %>);
```

Use this CSS/SCSS function instead:

```
background-image: url(asset-path("general/side_shadow.png", image));
```

Here's the doc for SCSS helpers : http://rubydoc.info/github/petebrowne/sprockets-sass/master/Sprockets/Sass/Functions

Hope this helps

Comment: Actually, that isn't the only reason, no. We are looking to do some pretty elaborate dynamic CSS class definitions so we can be as DRY as possible…